# Implement Subtotal feature of Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, folding, subtotal

Excel provides the Subtotal option from the Menu `Data` -> `Outline` -> `Subtotal`. It creates automatically the sub-sums and the possibility to fold the data. The image below demonstrates how the action transforms the sheet.

[image]

And this is exactly what I need to do via POI. I know how to set a subtotal function into a cell so I could calculate the intermediate sums by myself. But how do I enable this folding on the left border?

I realised there is the `groupRow()` method but those nested groups doesn't work like they should. If I use the following code I only get two groups. One large (1-7) and (1-3). The group (5-7) is missing and changing the order of the calls has no effect.

```
sheet.groupRow(1, 7);
sheet.groupRow(1, 3);
sheet.groupRow(5, 7);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a quite old verion of POI but this is how I did it:
I also needed multiple nested groups so I had a model for the rows where the indent level was stored as well (it was a tree so the indent was implicit). I traversed the model with a visitor to get the group start and end row numbers. Then called [HSSFSheet.groupRow](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#groupRow%28int,%20int%29) subsequently for each group. If I remember correctly, the order of the group calls is important.

Comment: Could you post some of your code? I still don't get those nested groups working.

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/iFkUFX3q This is grabbed outside from the context, but I hope it's still understandable. If not, I'll paste more. Group and groupOH does the same for different stuctures, so one of them should be enough.

Comment: Anyway, if you think it would help I could run a generation with logging all the row numbers grouped toghether and post is somewhere with a screenshot of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/apache-poi-excel-row-group-collapse.html

if you use `subtotal(9,<range>)` instead of `sum(<range>)`, you can perform nested groups as subtotal ignores cell with subtotal in its range

Answer (score 0):

With following library you can to calculate the subtotals that you want

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.bld-commons.excel</groupId>
  <artifactId>generator-excel</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This library is wrapper of apache poi.
Below the source code:

1. You create a class that represents the row of the table.
  ```
  package bld.generator.report.junit.entity;

  import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataConsolidateFunction;
  import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment;

  import bld.generator.report.excel.RowSheet;
  import bld.generator.report.excel.annotation.ExcelCellLayout;
  import bld.generator.report.excel.annotation.ExcelColumn;
  import bld.generator.report.excel.annotation.ExcelFont;
  import bld.generator.report.excel.annotation.ExcelSubtotal;
  import bld.generator.report.excel.annotation.ExcelSubtotals;

  @ExcelSubtotals(labelTotalGroup = "Total",endLabel = "total")
  public class SalaryRow implements RowSheet {

      @ExcelColumn(columnName = "Name", indexColumn = 0)
      @ExcelCellLayout
      private String name;
      @ExcelColumn(columnName = "Amount", indexColumn = 1)
      @ExcelCellLayout(horizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT)
      @ExcelSubtotal(dataConsolidateFunction = DataConsolidateFunction.SUM,excelCellLayout = @ExcelCellLayout(horizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT,font=@ExcelFont(bold = true)))
      private Double amount;
      
      public SalaryRow() {
          super();
      }
      public SalaryRow(String name, Double amount) {
          super();
          this.name = name;
          this.amount = amount;
      }
      public String getName() {
          return name;
      }
      public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
      }
      public Double getAmount() {
          return amount;
      }
      public void setAmount(Double amount) {
          this.amount = amount;
      }
      
  }
  ```
2. You create a class that represents the sheet.
  ```
  package bld.generator.report.junit.entity;

  import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

  import bld.generator.report.excel.SheetData;
  import bld.generator.report.excel.annotation.ExcelHeaderLayout;
  import bld.generator.report.excel.annotation.ExcelMarginSheet;
  import bld.generator.report.excel.annotation.ExcelSheetLayout;
  @ExcelSheetLayout
  @ExcelHeaderLayout
  @ExcelMarginSheet(bottom = 1.5,left = 1.5,right = 1.5,top = 1.5)
  public class SalarySheet extends SheetData<SalaryRow> {

      public SalarySheet(@Size(max = 31) String sheetName) {
          super(sheetName);
      }

  }
  ```
3. Class test
  ```
  package bld.generator.report.junit;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.junit.Before;
  import org.junit.Test;
  import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
  import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
  import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
  import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

  import bld.generator.report.excel.BaseSheet;
  import bld.generator.report.excel.GenerateExcel;
  import bld.generator.report.excel.data.ReportExcel;
  import bld.generator.report.junit.entity.SalaryRow;
  import bld.generator.report.junit.entity.SalarySheet;
  import bld.generator.report.utils.ExcelUtils;


  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  @SpringBootTest
  @ConfigurationProperties
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"bld.generator","bld.read"})
  @EnableTransactionManagement
  public class SalaryTest {

      private static final String PATH_FILE = "/mnt/report/";

      @Autowired
      private GenerateExcel generateExcel;

      /**
       * Sets the up.
       *
       * @throws Exception the exception
       */
      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
      }

      @Test
      public void testSalary() throws Exception {
          List<BaseSheet> listBaseSheet = new ArrayList<>();
          SalarySheet salarySheet=new SalarySheet("salary");
          salarySheet.getListRowSheet().add(new SalaryRow("a",2.0));
          salarySheet.getListRowSheet().add(new SalaryRow("a",2.0));
          salarySheet.getListRowSheet().add(new SalaryRow("a",2.0));
          salarySheet.getListRowSheet().add(new SalaryRow("a",2.0));
          salarySheet.getListRowSheet().add(new SalaryRow("c",1.0));
          salarySheet.getListRowSheet().add(new SalaryRow("c",1.0));
          salarySheet.getListRowSheet().add(new SalaryRow("c",1.0));
          salarySheet.getListRowSheet().add(new SalaryRow("c",1.0));
          listBaseSheet.add(salarySheet);
          
          ReportExcel report=new ReportExcel("test", listBaseSheet);
          
          byte[] byteReport = this.generateExcel.createFileXlsx(report);
          ExcelUtils.writeToFile(PATH_FILE,report.getTitle(), ".xlsx", byteReport);
          
      }
      
      

  }
  ```

Below the link of the project on github:

- https://github.com/bld-commons/dev-excel

Below the result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTcBR.jpg)